# How to read values from configuration.config file?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I have read a lot of post on being able to read from a web.config file. I am trying to relate what I have found to a configuration.config file and have not had much success. Below is the layout of my configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SessionTimeout>20</SessionTimeout>
  <ApplicationDirectory>C:\MyCompany\RunningFolder</ApplicationDirectory>
  <Rounding>0.5</Rounding>
</Configuration>
```

I want to be able to do is pull the  value but have not found a way to do this. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `webconfigurationmanager` for Web.config. And `ConfigurationManager` for other config.

Comment: There are lots of options for reading XML files in .NET (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx) for a start). If you want to use .NET's `.config` file support the file needs to use a specific kind of of XML document (which your's is not), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from using appsettings in your config file. Below is a link to msnd that explains them and how to read from them.

in your config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ApplicationDirectory" value="C:\MyCompany\RunningFolder" />
  <add key="Rounding" value="0.5" />
</appSettings>
```

In your code:

```
var ApplicationDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationDirectory"];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx